# Android Webview DOMException: The user agent does not support public key credentials

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to login to a webportal via the webview, after entering the password and clicking on login button I get the error, Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The user agent does not support public key credentials. Not sure how to handle it.